# Replace triple newlines with double newlines

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to perform some format cleaning in text files. I want to replace all triple(or more) new lines with double new lines and all double new lines with single new line.
First I open the file like this:

```
text = ""
with open(filename) as fp:  
   for cnt, line in enumerate(fp):
       text += line
```

but replacing the new lines like this: `text = re.sub(r'\n\n', '\n', text).strip()` 

 or like this `text = text.replace("\n\n", "\n")` replaces all (multiple) new lines with single new line.
 
 
What am I doing wrong?
 Thanks for any help and explanations.
 
**Edit**
 
I want to achieve that something like this:

```
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text


text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
```

becomes:

```
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
```

Comment: [This?](https://regex101.com/r/YoCEoE/1): `((?:\r\n?|\n)+)(?:\r\n?|\n)` replace with `\1`. Does 4 lines become 3 or 2, it's not clear?

Comment: @ctwheels is not working. Same result. Got everywhere single new line.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it's not working? What exactly is happening, what are you expecting?

Comment: Can you share what's the current output

Comment: You want to decrease one new line right ?

Comment: I want to replace all triple(or more) new lines with double new lines and all double new lines with single new line.

Comment: `re.sub(r'(\n{3,})|\n\n', lambda x: "\n\n" if x.group(1) else "\n", text)`

Comment: @Stribiżew  is not working. Same result. Got everywhere single new line.

Comment: Not sure why it does not, it does exactly what you said in the comment before. Use `with open(filename, 'r') as fp:  print( re.sub(r'(\n{3,})|\n\n', lambda x: "\n\n" if x.group(1) else "\n", fp.read()) )`

Comment: Great, it works. If you want, I would accept it as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
with open(filename, 'r') as fp: 
    print( re.sub(r'(\n{3,})|\n\n', lambda x: "\n\n" if x.group(1) else "\n", fp.read()) )
```

**NOTES**

- Run the regex on the whole file text, thus, use `fp.read()` to get it, do not read line by line
- The `(\n{3,})|\n\n` regex matches and captures 3 or more newlines into Group 1 or matches two newlines. If Group 1 matched, the replacement is a double newline, else, a single one. Since this is a conditional replacement, a callable (a lamda expression here) is used as the replacement argument.